# Is it safe to move IMAP message files around when using dovecot?

Tags: email, dovecot

I'm running postfix + dovecot, and all IMAP messages are in `/var/vmail/DOMAIN/USER`. I'd like to make a cron script that will look for messages for all users in a folder called 'False Positives,' `sa-learn` them as ham, and then move them into the inbox.

The question here is, is it safe to just `mv` one of these message files around? Or must it be done through some "official" means so the IMAP server is aware of the move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dovecot detects mailbox changes and rebuilds indexes automatically. Instead of 'mv' however, you could use dovecot's [doveadm](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm) command and save the unnecessary index rebuilds.

Something like this should work:

```
doveadm search -A mailbox 'False Positives' 2>/dev/null | while read user guid uid; do   doveadm fetch -u $user text mailbox-guid $guid uid $uid | sa-learn --ham ; doveadm move -u $user INBOX mailbox-guid $guid uid $uid ; done
Learned tokens from 1 message(s) (1 message(s) examined)
Learned tokens from 1 message(s) (1 message(s) examined)
Learned tokens from 1 message(s) (1 message(s) examined)
```

Explanation:

- `doveadm search -A mailbox 'False Positives'` ->  returns user/guid/uid of all messages in a "False Positives" Folder
- `doveadm fetch -u $user text mailbox-guid $guid uid $uid | sa-learn --ham` -> prints out the full message (header & body) and pipes it to sa-learn
- `doveadm move -u $user INBOX mailbox-guid $guid uid $uid` -> moves the message to INBOX

Comment: Strange. `sudo doveadm search -A mailbox FOLDERNAME` returns: doveadm(root): Error: User listing returned failure / doveadm: Error: Failed to iterate through some users

Comment: Well what do you know, I fixed it on my own. ;) Had to specify an iterate_query in one of the dovecot config files to work with my MySQL DB.

Comment: One fix to your code above: `doveadm search -A mailbox 'INBOX.False Positives'`

Comment: you probably have a different namespace config with INBOX prefix